# Change ionic slide box animation speed

Tags: ionic-framework, ioslides

I'm using $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.next() with a custom button to advance a slider. That works fine.My goal is to slow down the slide animation when someone actually pressed the next button.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly some versions of ionic have some inconsistency based on documentation. You can try `$ionicSlideBoxDelegate.slide(slideNumber, speed)`. And create an index on scope to control slideNumber. :/

> var slide = $ionicSlideBoxDelegate;
>
> var nextIndex = slider.currentIndex()+1;
>
> slider.slide(nextIndex,1000);